# Add a columns who tags the max and min value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, case, min

I want to add an extra column, where the min and max values of each group (ID) will appear.
Here how the table looks like:

select ID, VALUE from mytable

```
ID VALUE
1 4
1 1
1 7
2 2
2 5
3 7
3 3
```

Here is the result I want to get:

```
ID VALUE min_max_values
1 4 NULL
1 1 min
1 7 max
2 2 min
2 5 max
3 7 max
3 3 min
4 1 both
5 2 min
5 3 max
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions and a `case` expression:

```
select id, value,
    case
        when value = min_value and min_value = max_value then 'both'
        when value = min_value then 'min'
        when value = max_value then 'max'
    end as min_max_values
from (
    select t.*,
        min(value) over(partition by id) as min_value,
        max(value) over(partition by id) as max_value
    from mytable t
) t
```

The subquery is not strictly necessary, we could use the window `min()` and `max()` directly in the outer query. It is just there to avoid repeatedly typing the window function expressions in the outer query.